# terraform aws serverless v2 multi AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm following terraform documentation to create Aurora serverless v2 by terraform. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster#rds-serverless-v2-cluster

In terraform documentation, they have not mentioned how to create Aurora serverless v2 with multi AZ (read replica in other region for failover). Although, by aws console, I can create multi AZ Aurora serverless v2.

Any help is appreciated to create Aurora serverless v2 with multi AZ by terraform?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set it up becasuse  by default your data is stored across multiple AZs. From [docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.storage):

> The storage for each Aurora DB cluster consists of six copies of all your data, **spread across three AZs**. This built-in data replication applies regardless of whether your DB cluster includes any readers in addition to the writer. That way, your data is safe, even from issues that affect the compute capacity of the cluster.

Comment: In Aurora serverless v2, the storage is spread in all availability zones. There is no question about it. I'm more concern of DB failover mechanism in  Aurora serverless v2. Terraform doesn't provide any support to specify how to create Multi AZs(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html) As O said earlier, I can create Multi AZ Aurora serverless v2 without terraform in AWS console. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/26248

Comment: @ShahbazHussain There is no such thing as Multi-AZ in Aurora. Multi-AZ is for regular RDS only.

Comment: Even I have the same requirement. From UI, for Serverless v2 Aurora Postgresql, I can create Multi AZ, but not from Terraform. Any help would be really appreciated. The documentation is not there for this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I am using a custom module created from  https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds-aurora and also I saw one more link https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/24502. In this link, check the answer from msbainuk. You have to define additional instance, which will automatically create it as a Multi AZ. PFB the Code snippet from his answer.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.this.id
instance_class = "db.serverless"
engine = aws_rds_cluster.this.engine
engine_version = aws_rds_cluster.this.engine_version
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should create multiple `aws_rds_cluster_instance`s. Here's an [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster_instance#example-usage) from the docs:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
  count              = 2
  identifier         = "aurora-cluster-demo-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.default.id
  instance_class     = "db.r4.large"
  engine             = aws_rds_cluster.default.engine
  engine_version     = aws_rds_cluster.default.engine_version
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  cluster_identifier = "aurora-cluster-demo"
  availability_zones = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c"]
  database_name      = "mydb"
  master_username    = "foo"
  master_password    = "barbut8chars"
}
```

I believe the AWS console UI is masking over that. It's going to create 2x instances if you select "multi-az".